# Latent Dirichlet allocation and properties of digamma function

Tags: graph-theory, st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control, directed-graphs

In the paper Blei, D. M., Ng, A. Y., & Jordan, M. I. (2003). Latent Dirichlet Allocation. Journal of Machine Learning Research, 3(4–5), 993–1022. http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf

let $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \gamma_i} = \psi^{'}(\gamma_i)(\alpha_i + \sum_{n=1}^N \phi_{ni} - \gamma_i) - \psi^{'}(\Sigma_{j=1}^k \gamma_j)\sum_{j=1}^k(\alpha_j + \sum_{n=1}^N \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j) = 0$
yields $\gamma_i = \alpha_i + \Sigma_{n =1}^{N}\phi_{ni}$ (eqn. (17) in the paper's appendix or eqn.(7) in the paper's major part)

where, $\gamma_i$ is the variational Dirichlet parameter that governs the multinomial probability $\sum_{n=1}^N\phi_{ni} = 1$ ($N$ is the number of words in a document). see eqn(4) in the paper. $\alpha$ is the model Dirichlet parameter. $\psi$ is the digamma function. $L$ is the lower bound of the likelihood function.

This is equivalent to say that $\psi^{'}(\Sigma_{j=1}^k \gamma_j)\sum_{j=1}^k(\alpha_j + \sum_{n=1}^N \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j)$ is zero.

so either $\psi^{'}(\Sigma_{j=1}^k \gamma_j)$ is zero or $\sum_{j=1}^k(\alpha_j + \sum_{n=1}^N \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j)$ is zero

but which one is zero? And why?

clues: in Figure 6, which is the description of the algorithm,

$\gamma$ initialized to be for document $i$, $\gamma_i = \alpha_i + N/k$? where $k$ is the number of topics.

and $\phi_{ni}$ for the $i$th document is initialized to be $\phi_{ni} = 1/k$ , in this case $\sum_{j=1}^k(\alpha_j + \sum_{n=1}^N \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j) = 0$ holds since $(\alpha_j + \sum_{n=1}^N \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j) = 0$ holds for each document $j$, but this is just initialization.

in the iteration of the algorithm in Figure 6,  $\phi_{ni}$ is normalized to be sum up to 1 which means $(\alpha_j + \sum_{n=1}^N \phi_{nj} - \gamma_j) = (\alpha_j + 1 - \gamma_j)$, this seems not to be zero?

Comment: The link is broken, use https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=944937

Answer (score 0):

well, it turns out that we do not need to seek for other solutions, since letting $\alpha_j- \gamma_j = 1$ is a solution?